Term for sensor noise which depends on value (percent of reading)
I feel that this concept must come up all the time and I just don't know a good statistical term for it.
With e.g. a laser measurement tool, the errors can probably be assumed to be to normally distributed given a specific distance but the amount of error rises with the distance. Uncertainty-wise it can be called "percent of reading".
In many cases there is an underlying assumption of data homoskedasticity so I'm looking for ways to handle these kind of errors but handling heteroskedasticity in general is probably not what I'm after when it comes to, for example, smoothing.

I just saw "signal-dependent noise" being is used in the context I'm interested in.
